# Android Map v2 Program Crashes at start

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I've searched for a week and tested all the solutions said, but nonestrong text worked!
I've tried every thing said in:

[Google Maps Android API v2 - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

and lot's of others SO solutions...

I tried to test on my Mobile Phone but it crashes in start.

Main Activity:

```
package com.google.balakharekechi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

and the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.balakharekechi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyB_Exrzd7O0rzadCpWMvk6hdz5QUJx9DTk" />
</application>
```

there is no error...

i've tried with google-play-servies 6171000 and 5077000 same problem.

tried extends FragmentActivity also and the same problem...

the Log Cat with a Google Nexus 4-4.4.4 simulation on GenyMotion:

```
01-12 15:30:34.240: D/libEGL(1869): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
01-12 15:30:34.244: D/(1869): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8ee21c0, tid 1869
01-12 15:30:34.268: D/libEGL(1869): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
01-12 15:30:34.268: D/libEGL(1869): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
01-12 15:30:34.340: W/EGL_genymotion(1869): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-12 15:30:34.344: E/OpenGLRenderer(1869): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
01-12 15:30:34.344: E/OpenGLRenderer(1869): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
01-12 15:30:34.360: E/OpenGLRenderer(1869): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
01-12 15:30:34.364: E/OpenGLRenderer(1869): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
01-12 15:30:34.364: D/OpenGLRenderer(1869): Enabling debug mode 0
01-12 15:30:37.400: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1869): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5077000 but found 2012110
01-12 15:30:37.408: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1869): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5077000 but found 2012110
```

and on my real mobile phone, crashes after some seconds...

these are LogCat Errors of my real device debugging:

```
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.balakharekechi/com.google.balakharekechi.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:167)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1884)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.google.balakharekechi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5125)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2289)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    ... 11 more
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ck.a(Unknown Source)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.i.a(Unknown Source)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.el.a(Unknown Source)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ab.a(Unknown Source)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.aa.a(Unknown Source)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:920)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1206)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2159)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
01-17 14:26:18.491: E/AndroidRuntime(24322):    ... 20 more
```

plz help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You should go the the SDK Manager and download the last google-play-services sdk from there:

[image]

Then copy it to your project from the:

SDK/extras/google/google_play_service to your project and reference this one.

This should be the correct google play service version.

Comment: i checked 3 versions of Google Play but no answer!

Comment: could you look for the value: google_play_services_version you in you current google play services library and verify that it's the requested value in the error message?

Comment: it Rev. 22 and checked as installed in my sdk manager. and the  warning _"Google Play services out of date.  Requires 6171000 but found 2012110"_ is showed when running on GenyMotion emulator! so i think Geny's google play is out of date! but what about my real device? it's up to date!

Comment: My trouble solved!

there was a mistaken in the name of new project creating in "Google Developers Console" of mine. (a different between my eclipse project name and developer console project name)

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on the Google Android Map v2 on the API console ? 
 
When you import your project you need to check the box "Copy projects into workspace"

Comment: yes, i did it, tanx for ur reply but my trouble solved:
take a look at my comment under Emil's post:

there was a mistaken in the name of new project creating in "Google Developers Console" of mine. (a different between my eclipse project name and developer console project name)

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

The log-cat was clear to you, it identified the problem as:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Well i've already done that, tanx for ur reply but my trouble solved:
take a look at my comment under Emil's post:

there was a mistaken in the name of new project creating in "Google Developers Console" of mine. (a different between my eclipse project name and developer console project name)